# store a table in localstorage and retrieve the same on the second page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

i have a payment table as given below

```
<table id="payment">
    <thead >
        <tr>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody >
        <tr>
            <td>tv</td>
            <td>$40.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>phone</td>
            <td>$20.00</td>
            </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>car</td>
            <td>$40.00</td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>dress</td>
            <td>$20.00</td>
        </tr>                    
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I tried to store the table on localstorage

```
  //gets table
    var myTable = document.getElementById('payment');

    //gets rows of table
    var rowLength = myTable.rows.length;

    //loops through rows    
    for (i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){

        //gets cells of current row  
        var oCells = myTable.rows.item(i).cells;

        //gets amount of cells of current row
        var cellLength = oCells.length;

        //loops through each cell in current row
        for(var j = 0; j < cellLength; j++){

        // get your cell info here

            var cellVal = oCells.item(j).innerHTML;
            var myData = [ cellVal, cellVal ];
            localStorage.setItem( 'productdata', myData );

          }
```

in page2 i want to display the table as like in the first page..confused by how to save and retrieve localstorage data. And display the table exactly on page2. any solution !

Comment: why you want to do this ? and not by ajax. BTW you are overwriting  `productdata`

Comment: Apart from the fact that I can't see the reason why you want to do it this way, you're overwriting the same key in `localStorage` `(rowLength * cellLength)` times. You could instead store the `outerHTML` of the table `localStorage.setItem("productdata", myTable.outerHTML)` but that brings us back to my first sentence.

Comment: ok. the table is a cost estimator and i just wants to pass data into second page. how to use ajax to do the same. pls guide me how to store these values on data and submit form

Answer (score 0):

I think u can just store as `innerHTML`

```
localStorage.setItem('table', document.getElementById('payment').innerHTML)
```

And read as this in second page

```
document.getElementById('payment').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('table')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following logic to first get the data from the table. Take to look this example

```js
const table = document.querySelector('table');
const tbody = table.tBodies[0];

function getDataset() {
    const rows = Array.from(tbody.rows);
    const dataset = rows.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
        const [item, price] = Array.from(currentValue.cells);
        const data = {
            item: item.textContent,
            price: price.textContent
        };

        accumulator.push(data);
        
        return accumulator;
    }, []);


    return dataset;
}

const dataset = getDataset();

console.log(dataset);
```

```html
<table id="payment">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>tv</td>
        <td>$40.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>phone</td>
        <td>$20.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>car</td>
        <td>$40.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>dress</td>
        <td>$20.00</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The next step is store the dataset in localstorage in the example code you can replace the `console.log(dataset)` line for `localStorage.setItem('dataset', JSON.stringify(dataset));`. If you refresh the page and inspect the localstorage under the key dataset you get the following data `localStorage.getItem('dataset')`

```
 "[{\"item\":\"tv\",\"price\":\"$40.00\"},{\"item\":\"phone\",\"price\":\"$20.00\"},{\"item\":\"car\",\"price\":\"$40.00\"},{\"item\":\"dress\",\"price\":\"$20.00\"}]"
```

Now in the next page you can retrieve and parse this stringified representation of your data to natural javascript array and objects. This with the following code `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dataset'))`

Finally you need to render the table again. You could this in many ways here one of them:

```
function render() {
    const dataset = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('dataset'));
    const output = document.querySelector('#output');

    const rows = dataset.map(data => {
        return `
            <tr>
                <td>${data.item}</td>
                <td>${data.price}</td>
            </tr>`;
    }).join('');

    output.innerHTML = `
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                ${rows}
            </tbody>
        </table>`;
}

render();
```

The render method assumes that there is some div with id output, where you draw the table with the data obtained from the localstorage